# Python 2.7: passing values to getpass

Tags: python, python-2.7

On Windows (specifically Win Server 2008 R2), I need to repeatedly execute an existing python script that comes with our product repeated.  The intention of this script was to be called occasionally and the input is expected to be manual.  However, I end up having to call this script hundreds of times.

So, I'm trying to automate the calls to this script (and other related scripts) with an additional python script.  Where I'm getting hung up is that the "out of the box" script I am calling uses getpass.getpass() for password input.

In my automation script, I've tried using subrocess pipe.communicate to pass the password values to the base script.  But I can't get it to work.  Here's the relevant code in my automation script:

```
p = Popen(coreScriptCmd, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
x = p.stdout.readline().rstrip()
print x     #for debugging
x = p.communicate(args.pwd1+"\n"+args.pwd2)[0].rstrip()
print x     #for debugging
```

As I said though, this doesn't work when the subprocess being called is using getpass.getpass() to ask for it's input.  Here's the if statement in the core code where I'm running into trouble:

```
elif cmd == 'update-user':
if 'password1' not in globals():
    password1 = getpass.getpass(mgmtusername + " password:")
if 'dbpassword' not in globals():
    dbpassword = getpass.getpass(dbusername + " password:")
checkAccessDb(hostname, database, mgmtusername, password1, dbusername, dbpassword)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to programmaticly pass values to getpass() in the subscript?

Comment: Do you plan to still use the script manually?

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately, we still have to be able to use the script manually.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I'm not sure what the original script looks like. But, in the case that it will still need to be usable from the command line, I would recommend this.

I would modify the original script to accept an argument. For example, let's say that the getpass is inside a function like this...

```
def run_script():
    paswd = getpass.getpass("Please enter the password:")
```

Try modifying it to something like this:

```
def run_script(cmdlin = True):
    if cmdlin:
        paswd = getpass.getpass("Please enter the password:")
    else:
        # get password using another method
```

The other method could be anything you choose, pass it as an argument, grab it from a file, etc..

Once it is setup like this, just call it passing in "cmdlin" argument as false.

**Edit**: Using the subprocess module you should be able to use [communicate](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to send the password over

Also, I found the [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) library that might help in your situation

Comment: I'm trying to get away from modifying the core code.  I can make it work by switching the core code from getpass() to print(...) and pwd=raw_input().  But then every time we get a quarterly update of the core script I have to modify it again.

Comment: I edited my answer with a couple other things that might work for you.

Comment: I looked at pexpect, but it looks like a unix only solution.  I'm stuck on windows.

Comment: @MikeM. Not all features are available on windows but since v4 it does support windows ([docs](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html#windows))

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible because of your code
 `x = p.stdout.readline().rstrip()` . stdout.readline() is a blocking call and it will block as long as there is nothing to output. Try commenting out that line and see if it works.Also sharing the content of "coreScriptCmd" would help to find the root cause in a better way.

Comment: The core script is very large.  I added into my problem description the core script lines where my automation code fails to communicate with the core script.